# UITextfield Custom Position moved up because of different iPhone sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I have several custom UITextfields in my app. I started this app on Xcode 5 and ran on iphone 5 simulator. After Xcode updated to Xcode 6, I ran the app on iPhone 6 simulator. Now all the textfield positions moved up because of large screen size. I just wanted to know is there anything I could do so that the positions of textfields automatically get adjusted depending upon the iPhone models.

Comment: Build an interface that supports iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild your interface to handle the different screen sizes.  In particular, you need to work with the AutoLayout feature to help determine how you want everything to scale/move/position based on multiple screen sizes. This can be done via the Storyboard (easier but sometimes frustrating) or in code (harder at first but more control later). I usually use Storyboards and it's worked great on several projects.

Do you want it centered and respecting your original layout and margins? a certain distance from the top or sides? everything scaled up appropriately? All these things can be done with AutoLayouts.

Check out the great tutorial here for more information:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1